# Notifications not displaying, notification API

Tags: javascript, html, notifications

When creating notifications with the notification API the notifications are not displaying.

I was recently trying to use the notification api in order to create a simple notification and display it. Eventually I was going to use notifications In an app that I am building. The requesting permission step went smoothly but when I created the notification It simply did not display.

I know that my browser supports the notification api and I do not have them blocked. I am also not using a mobile device and I am using the latest version of chrome. These notification are not displaying anywhere, including websites with ssh encryption.

Here is my code:

```
async function notify(data) {
  function createNotification(data) {
    const notification = new Notification(data.title, {
      icon: data.icon,
      body: data.body
    })

    return notification
  }

  function checkNotifications() {
    if(Notification) {
      return true
    } else {
      alert('Notifications are not supported on this browser.')
      return false
    }
  }

  if(checkNotifications()) {
    if(Notification.permission === 'granted') {
      createNotification(data)
    } else {
      if(await Notification.requestPermission() === 'granted') {
        console.log(createNotification(data))
      } else {
        alert('you will not recive notifications')
      }
    }
  }
}

notify({title: 'test', body: '<b>hello</b>', icon: '../logo.png'})
```

Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>website</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
  <body>

    <script type='text/javascript' src='./notification.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Expected results:

The notification displays

actual results:

No error, but no notification either.

EDIT:

The notifications work If I set the notification to 'allow' instead of 'ask'.

Comment: this worked for me https://codesandbox.io/s/pom94o8kx

Comment: @Fraction It did not for me

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this in manifest?

```
"permissions": [
          "contentSettings"
        ],
```

And then in your script...

```
chrome.contentSettings.notifications.set({primaryPattern:'<all_urls>',setting:'allow'});
```

Sorry, are you server side or client?

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSettings

Comment: Where is that `chrome` variable coming from?

Comment: Sorry, I've never used manifest, could you explain to me what It is? Thankyou.

Comment: To take advantage of Chrome APIs you need to have a manifest.json

Comment: I am not using chrome notifications. I am using the desktop notification api.

Comment: OK, if you are not the browser author then just ignore the above.

Comment: @ user4723924 what do you mean by browser author

Comment: Is it your Chromium iframe you are operating in?

Comment: I am creating a html file and then opening it

Comment: The it's for a website (server side) I'll delete my post.

Comment: @ user4723924 sorry When you said server I was not sure if you meant that I was the creator or if you meant the I was using node.js. Guess I should have figured that out sooner.

Comment: at the very bottom of the question you will see: share edit flag delete. all in small greyed out text.

Comment: are you sure that you are looking at your post and not my post?

Comment: that's ok. I was at the top of 'interesting' a bit ago so I should be fine. @user4723924

Comment: the request part is working fine, it's just the display.

Answer (score 0):

Check your windows settings has notifications enabled.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-notification-settings-in-windows-10-ddcbbcd4-0a02-f6e4-fe14-6766d850f294

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-notification-and-action-settings-in-windows-10-8942c744-6198-fe56-4639-34320cf9444e

Start > Settings > System > Notifications and actions

You can also click on the notification hub on the bottom right of your screen and then click on manage notifications. You may have them enabled, but you could also be blocking chrome based ones.